# Google charts tooltips number format scientific

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, number-formatting

How do you set the google charts' tooltips number format to 'scientific'? I have tried the google.visualization.NumberFormat but did not have any luck. I can set the vAxis fine as shown here: [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npMs3.png)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetAreaChartData",
        type: "post",
        data: formContainer.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var rows = data.length;
            var cols = data[0].length;

            tdata.addColumn('datetime', 'DateTime');
            tdata.addColumn('number', 'Frequency Offset');


            tdata.addRows(data.length);
            for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

                tdata.setCell(i, 0, new Date(data[i][0]));
                for (var j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
                    var value = parseFloat(data[i][j]);
                    tdata.setCell(i, j, value);
                }
            }

            var options = {

                width: 900,
                height: 500,
                lineWidth: 1,
                pointSize: 0,
                legend: 'none',
                vAxis: {
                    title: "Frequency Offset",
                    format:"scientific"
                },
            };

            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ format: 'scientific' });
            formatter.format(tdata, 1);

            var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(tdata, options);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) does not have an option for --> `'format'`

use --> `'pattern'` -- instead...

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: 'scientific' });
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.